# List of options is making scrollbar in my modal and do not lay on top of modal

Tags: css

I have a dialog, and inside of that I have a dropdown. Initially my dialog is overflowing in the y-direction. But when I add position: absolute (or relative) and a larger z-index to my options for my dropdown, it will not lay on top of the dialog. It causes a scrollbar in the y-direction, because the options are too long for the dialog. The z-index only works if the dialog have overflow: unset. Is there not a way to both have a scroll inside the dialog, when the content are too long, and also display the options on top of the dialog, if it pops open?

```
<div class="think-of-this-as-dialog" style="overflow-y: auto; z-index: 1">
   <div class="think-of-this-as-dropdown" >
      <div class="think-of-this-as-list-of-options" style="position: absoute; z-index: 100"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I can see that the problem is the dialog which have an overflow-y: auto, such that the options triggers the scroll to appear. But I need the scroll feature when the content inside the dialog becomes too long.

If I remove the overflow-y: auto, then it works, but as mentioned: I need the funtionality.

Comment: Can you share your HTML part?

Comment: @RohanRao I tried to add some code for you